# How to import escaped non-ASCII characters inside comment text?

Tags: import

I have a file, say temp.m, with a single line `(* foo\[AAcute]bar *)`. What function call should I use to read the content of the file into the expression `"foo\[AAcute]bar"` inside Mathematica?

BTW, by "escaped non-ASCII characters" I mean objects like `\[AAcute]`. What's accurate term to call them in Wolfram Language terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be considered a duplicate of [Showing special characters in text containing unicode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26215/121) even though that question does not directly relate to importing.  Applying Sjoerd's method:

```
Import["temp.m", "String"]

ToExpression["\"" <> % <> "\""]
```

> ```
> "(* fooábar *)"
> ```

If you want only the content of comments then:

```
Import["temp.m", "Comments"]
ToExpression["\"" <> % <> "\""]
```

> ```
> "fooábar"
> ```

Comment: For mission-critical purposes such as launching nuclear missiles, is the `ToExpression` safe?

Comment: @qazwsx Let me think about that.  At least a minor additional layer of security might be had with the use of `ToHeldExpression` in place of `ToExpression`.